# mercurial -- "merge" by abandoning one changeset

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have two heads, let's call them "A" (the good head) and "B" (the bad head).  I want to merge them by taking everything from A and nothing from B.  Basically, my merge of A and B is A.

When I try hg merge, it starts asking me about this file and that, and inevitably I get into trouble.  I don't want any of that!  How can I tell it to merge them and end up with A, preferably without any intermediate steps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing I came across and started using recently on some personal repos was just using the close-branch switch with commit. e.g.

```
$ hg update B
$ hg commit --close-branch -m "Abandoning branch"
```

In my reasoning, if you're blowing away one branch in favor of the other entirely, it's simply not a merge and it's silly to call it that. I'm relatively new to hg myself, and I seem to recall that --close-branch has not been around since the beginning and maybe that's why it doesn't have as much traction as the merging gyrations I usually see.

Comment: Agree. If you have a *bad* branch, you should get rid of it by closing the branch or by stripping it. If you merge it, you make the *bad* branch an inherent part the history graph, any *good* future changes will have it as an ancestor -- but actually you abandoned it.

Comment: What is the functional difference between using "close-branch" and using merge=internal:local?  Does it look different in the hg log output?

Answer (score 27):

**From the Mercurial tips at section 22**. Keep "My" or "Their" files when doing a merge.

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks

Occasionally you want to merge two heads, but you want to throw away all changes from one of the heads, a so-called dummy merge. You can override the merge by using the ui.merge configuration entry:

```
$ hg --config ui.merge=internal:local merge  #keep my files
$ hg --config ui.merge=internal:other merge  #keep their files
```

Here local means parent of working directory, other is the head you want to merge with. This will leave out updates from the other head.

To merge X into the current revision without letting any of the changes from X come through, do:

```
hg --config ui.merge=internal:fail merge X
hg revert --all --rev .
```

**The other approach** is mentioned in : https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches

```
$ hg update -C tip # jump to one head
$ hg merge otherhead # merge in the other head
$ hg revert -a -r tip # undo all the changes from the merge
$ hg commit -m "eliminate other head" # create new tip identical to the old
```

Comment: Though the original question may not be for a true merge, this was the first answer I found for my problem which is. And I even breezed through the Mercurial Merge and Tips and Tricks pages. Thanks!

Comment: It's been reported to me that hg will still add new files from the "other" branch with you use internal:local merging algorithm.  That seems like a bug, but caveat emptor.